# Java hashmap.get() in c++

Tags: c++, stdmap

In java you could have something like:

```
Map<Foo, List<Bar>> things;

for(Foo foo : things.getKeySet()){
    List<bar> = things.get(foo);
}
```

Is there an equivalent for c++, maybe in std::map? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (ArrayList) and maybe [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) (HashMap) and [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (LinkedList)

For example:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};

int main()
{
    std::map<Foo, std::vector<Bar>> things;

    for(auto& thing: things) {
        const Foo& foo = thing.first; // key
        std::vector<Bar>& bars = thing.second; // value

        // use foo & bars here
    }
}
```

**Note:** A [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) requires that a comparison operator be defined for user defined types like `Foo`:

```
struct Foo
{
    int i = 0;
    Foo(int i): i(i) {}

    // need a comparison operator for ordered containers
    bool operator<(const Foo& foo) const { return i < foo.i; }
};
```